# How to create "Category" column based on "description column"

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I'm working on a bank transaction dataset with a "Description" column that contains a single phrase that describing the transaction. I would like to group the similar transactions in the dataset under categories.

For example, if the description of transaction1 = "Roger - B111" and description of transaction 2 = "Internet bill 293290", then I'd like to to change both of their descriptions to "Telecommunication".

The final result I'm looking for, is a new column called "Transaction Category", this column would have different category levels (Food, Telecommunication, bills).

Any ideas of the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: First of all, is this python, pandas, or SQL? Please don't say "all of them", ask a specific question please and make it clear what language/software you're using. SQL has a lot of dialects as well.

Comment: I have the dataset in Big Query, so I can query it using SQL. I'm also using Python on a subset of the data to see if I can work it out in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`, but you have to figure out the logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when description in ('Roger - B111', 'Internet bill 293290')
             then 'Telecommunication'
             . . .
        end) as category
from t;
```

Comment: thank you. usually, there are many variations of the same type of transaction, like: "Internet Bill T232" and "Internet Bill 1111". do you think using the like operator on a single word would be a good idea?

Comment: @AdamObaid . . . If that is what your logic requires, then use `like`.